# How to show numbers for each paragraph in Swift label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, paragraph

I am getting string from server is like below, Due to privacy policy I have added some static text.

> "\n1. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen . \n2. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen \n3. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen…\n"

The above text I have to show like below format.

```
1. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen .

2. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen

3. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen…
```

Also the index numbers should have different color to show in label.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `\n` character is a newline character, so it will be handled by the `UILabel` for you. So, all you need to do is to set the `foregroundColor` for matches of the number at the start of each line. E.g.

```swift
let string = "\n1. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen . \n2. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen \n3. You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen…\n"
    .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\n\n")

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"^\d+\."#, options: .anchorsMatchLines)
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
regex.enumerateMatches(in: string, range: range) { result, _, _ in
    guard let range = result?.range else { return }
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
}

label.numberOfLines = 0
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

That will yield:

[image]

That includes a border (rendered with with `label.layer.borderColor` and `layer.borderWidth`), so you can see precisely how the text is laid out in the label.

---

If you want it to look like a real list, with indentation, you would probably have to reformat the text into HTML (which would, itself, be an annoying exercise), then back to a `NSAttributedString` and format the numbers there:

```swift
let string = """
    <style>
    li {
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        margin-bottom: 12pt;
    }
    </style>
    <ol>
    <li>You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen .</li>
    <li>You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen</li>
    <li>You are Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen Lorem ipsum doller sit amen…</li>
    </ol>
    """
guard let data = string.data(using: .utf16) else { return }

let attributedString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"^\s*\d+\."#, options: .anchorsMatchLines)
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
regex.enumerateMatches(in: attributedString.string, range: range) { result, _, _ in
    guard let range = result?.range else { return }
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
}

label.attributedText = attributedString
```

If you know your CSS, you might be inclined to add a coloring via the `<style>` for `ol:before`, but that does not appear to work. (If you’re not up on your CSS and didn’t follow what I said, just ignore it, as it doesn’t work, anyway.)

Anyway, if you go through all of that work, that yields:

[image]

Comment: Perfectly working! Thank you Rob

Comment: Rob in starting text its coming two paragraphs empty which should be removed. pls check here https://pasteboard.co/6OsixDnhl2Ov.png

Comment: Are you talking about the leading `\n`? You can do `.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)` to get rid of any leading (and trailing) newline characters.

Comment: No, I just want to remove white space before 1st paragraph

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: It's removing one line only, there are two empty lines. So, How to remove those two lines, Any suggestions

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative - When `trimmingCharacters(in:)`, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIyVG.jpg (showing border with `label.layer.borderColor` and `label.layer.borderWidth`). Definitely no leading blank lines. Perhaps you are not letting it adjust label height based upon content? E.g., if I use a fixed size (or otherwise don’t let it automatically adjust the height based upon the content), then I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/igzOr.jpg. Looks like blank lines, but it’s just centering the text vertically. Or maybe something else. But trimming works. I suspect something else is going on.

Comment: I am doing dynamic height based on text for the label

Comment: Well, we don't have enough here to diagnose your problem, but you can see that it’s working for me. I might advise posting a separate question with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can diagnose what's going on in your case.

Comment: I have fixed that issue by changing label properties, Thank you @Rob